# Qualifier on function type .. has unspecified behavior

Tags: c++, factory

```
#ifndef SHAPEFACTORY_H_
#define SHAPEFACTORY_H_

#include <istream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

#include "shape.h"

typedef Shape *(createShapeFunction)(void);
/* thrown when a shape cannot be read from a stream */
class WrongFormatException { };

class ShapeFactory {

public:

    static void registerFunction(const std::string &string, const createShapeFunction *shapeFunction);
    static Shape *createShape(const std::string &string);
    static Shape *createShape(std::istream &ins);

private:

    std::map<std::string, createShapeFunction *> creationFunctions;
    ShapeFactory();
    static ShapeFactory *getShapeFactory();
};

#endif
```

This is the header, I have not implemented any method yet, but I am getting the following warning:

```
Qualifier on function type 'createShapeFunction' (aka 'Shape *()') has unspecified behavior
```

ps: this header was given by my teacher and as a homework I have to implement the methods

Comment: You need a star inside the first set of parens: `typedef Shape* (*createShapeFunction)(void);`

Comment: @metal, could you please explain me a bit why is that?

Comment: @Teodora I've explained it in my answer.

Comment: In short, what's in the first set of parentheses is part of the type and it needs to be a pointer. The syntax for function pointers has always struck me as a bit weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a silly warning message. It's not unspecified, but the `const` qualification you've put on the second argument to `registerFunction` will be ignored.

Let's look at the `typedef` of `createShapeFunction`:

```
typedef Shape *(createShapeFunction)(void);
```

You can read this type as "a function that takes no arguments and returns a `Shape*`". So then you have an argument of this type:

```
const createShapeFunction*
```

This would be a pointer to a `const` function type. There's no such thing as a `const` function type, so the `const` is ignored and the argument type is equivalent to `createShapeFunction*`. That is, a pointer to the function type defined above.

It's possible that you meant for `createShapeFunction` to be a function pointer type itself:

```
typedef Shape *(*createShapeFunction)(void);
```

Now you can read this type as "pointer to function taking no arguments and returning `Shape*`". Then that would make the argument `const createShapeFunction*` a pointer to a `const` function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is being issued because the type `const createShapeFunction*` attempts to create a `const`-qualified function type (since `createShapeFunction` is defined as the type of a function which returns a `Shape*` and accepts no argument). This is what the C++11 Standard has to say about it (Paragraph 8.5.3/6):

> **The effect of a cv-qualifier-seq in a function declarator is not the same as adding cv-qualification on top
>   of the function type. In the latter case, the cv-qualifiers are ignored**. [ Note: a function type that has a
>   cv-qualifier-seq is not a cv-qualified type; there are no cv-qualified function types. —end note ] [ Example:
>
> ```
> typedef void F();
> struct S {
>     const F f; // OK: equivalent to: void f();
> };
> ```
>
> —end example ]

Therefore, the compiler is warning you that you may have meant something else rather than what you actually wrote, because `const` qualifications on function types would just be ignored.